# How to convert a Python file to APK file for Android using Buildozer?

Tags: python

Can you tell me where this error came from?
I get this error in google `colab`

```
 Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy==2.1.0,arabic-reshaper==3.0.0,python-bidi==0.4.2', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:....
```

I want to convert `py` file to `apk` file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.